# I am new to C and I am trying to learn to use structs, my unix app won't run and says EXC_BAD_ACCES. HElP!

Tags: c, xcode, struct, typedef, exc-bad-access

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int num;
    struct contact;

```
struct contact {
    double foneNumber;
    char firstName;
    char lastName;
    };
typedef struct contact cntct;

cntct bob;

bob.foneNumber = 15555555555;
bob.firstName = "bob";
bob.lastName = "builder";


cntct fudge;

fudge.foneNumber = 15444444444;
fudge.firstName = "fudge";
fudge.lastName = "cornelius";

cntct Siddhartha;


Siddhartha.foneNumber = 15333333333;
Siddhartha.firstName = "Siddhartha";
Siddhartha.lastName = "Gautama";

while (1) {
printf("Would you like to see contact 1, 2, or 3 (0 to quit)?");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Phone Number:  %lg", bob.foneNumber);
            printf("\nFirst Name:  %s", bob.firstName);
            printf("\nLast Name:  %s", bob.lastName);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Phone Number:  %lg", fudge.foneNumber);
            printf("\nFirst Name:  %s", fudge.firstName);
            printf("\nLast Name:  %s", fudge.lastName);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Phone Number:  %lg", Siddhartha.foneNumber);
            printf("\nFirst Name:  %s", Siddhartha.firstName);
            printf("\nLast Name:  %s", Siddhartha.lastName);
            break;
        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("huh?");
            return 0;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you just post code like this, we aren't likely to help you out.  Can you describe what the code does?  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any suspicions about what's wrong?  This site is not for "please fix my code for me," but if you've made it clear that you've put in a good honest effort and that you're honestly stuck, we'd be glad to help.

Comment: Adding a phrase like "HELP!!!" to your question's title will only cause other users to either ignore your question or post a comment like this one. Please don't do it again in the future. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your struct you should use char pointers to hold the address of strings, not chars:

```
struct contact {
    double foneNumber;
    char * firstName;
    char * lastName;
    };
```

Otherwise, when you call `printf` with `%s`, it expects the parameter to be an `address` to char, but instead it gets some value (which is the value of the char) and this is in most cases an invalid address.